# Error for URL hack with Today Date

Tags: custom-button

i have an error.
I have create a new button for create opportunity with default field value but in the Open Date and Close Date field he has an error, i have the right format of date but he accept them only when i choose the date on the calendar

```
/lightning/o/Opportunity/new?defaultFieldValues=
    
    AM_Open_Date__c={!TODAY()},
    CloseDate={!TODAY() + 365},
    
    &count=1&nooverride=1&useRecordTypeCheck=1&navigationLocation=RELATED_LIST&uid={!Opportunity.Id}&ws=%2Flightning%2Fr%2FAccount%2F{!Opportunity.Id}%2Fview
```

Comment: For Date fields can you try {!TEXT(TODAY() )}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try passing the date fields by converting them to string as below

```
 AM_Open_Date__c={!TEXT(TODAY())},
 CloseDate={!TEXT(TODAY() + 365)},
```

Comment: Oh thanks it's work !